# InvalidAlgorithmParameterException

Tags: security, db2, java

I wrote a GUi java program which brings data from db2 and shwos into a JtextArea when click a Jbutton.

I have used encription for ID/PAssword as below code

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("securityMechanism",
Integer.toString(DB2BaseDataSource.ENCRYPTED_USER_AND_PASSWORD_SECURITY));
properties.setProperty("user","myuserid");
properties.setProperty("password","mypassword"); myConn =
DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties);
```

It runs fine when i run it in eclipse.

Just created a runnable jar file using export option (selecting package reqd libs into generated jar option).
When I double click the jar file it shows the gui window but when i click the button it does not gettting any data.

I saved data base connectivity logs into a file which shows.....

```
Error msg: [jcc][1071][10615][4.8.86] Caught java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException 
while initializing EncryptionManager.  
See attached Throwable for details. ERRORCODE=-4223, SQLSTATE=null
SQLSTATE: null
Error code: -4223
```

Please help to solve this problem.
Thanks,

Comment: Sounds like [this problem](http://www.dbvis.com/forum/thread.jspa?threadID=3453).

Comment: What is the JRE version? Which version is installed in your pc? Which Eclipse release are you use Juno, Helios, Galileo?

Comment: seems like problem with your `cacerts` google it

Comment: same issue without answer, same code: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10649009/1782379

Comment: Its not pure eclipse. Its RDz(IBM Rational developer for System Z with Java 8.0.3) based on eclipse. 

And the PC control panel shows JAVA 6 standard edition.